# How to effectively write -sm, -md, -lg padding classes in LESS

Tags: css, less, mixins

I'm trying to create standard classes that can be used to add different amounts of padding. This would be added to the individual elements within the DOM to control padding/margins. I'd like to eventually leverage it for different sizes and for margins as well. This is how I've begun to write it in LESS, but is there a shorter way to write this?

```
@padding-sm: 5px;
@padding-md: 10px;
@padding-lg: 20px;

.padding-sm {
  padding: @padding-sm;
}
.padding-sm-h {
  padding-right: @padding-sm;
  padding-left: @padding-sm;
}
.padding-sm-v {
  padding-top: @padding-sm;
  padding-bottom: @padding-sm;
}
.padding-sm-top {
  padding-top: @padding-sm;
}
.padding-sm-right {
  padding-right: @padding-sm;
}
.padding-sm-bottom {
  padding-bototm: @padding-sm;
}
.padding-none {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For LESS 1.7+

This uses the `.for` looping code that can be found [here](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/src/for.less), which is normally recommended to be saved in a separate less file and imported, like so:

```
@import "for";
```

Assuming that code is in place, whether by import or hard copied in, then you can build the following mixin:

```
.setPadding(@size) {
    @s: ~"-@{size}";
    @getSize: ~"padding@{s}";
    @getValue: @@getSize;
    @directions: top right bottom left;
    @pairs: h right left, v top bottom;
    .appendPadding() {.padding& { @props();}}
    @{s} {
        //set all directions
        & { 
            @props: {padding: @getValue;};
            .appendPadding(); 
        }
        //set paired directions
        & {
            .for(@pairs); .-each(@pair) {
                @name: extract(@pair, 1);
                @one: extract(@pair, 2);
                @two: extract(@pair, 3);
                &-@{name} {
                    @props: {
                      padding-@{one}: @getValue; 
                      padding-@{two}: @getValue;
                    };
                    .appendPadding();
                }
            }
        }
        //set four base directions
        & {
            .for(@directions); .-each(@dir) {
                &-@{dir} {
                    @props: {padding-@{dir}: @getValue;};
                    .appendPadding();
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Now the above looks vastly more complicated than your original code, but it gets its power by its ability to *easily* reproduce for all your sizing levels. So with the above code, then the following minimal amount of code defines your three groups into CSS as you are desiring:

```
@padding-sm: 5px;
@padding-md: 10px;
@padding-lg: 20px;

.setPadding(sm);
.setPadding(md);
.setPadding(lg);
.padding-none {
  padding: 0;
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.padding-sm {
  padding: 5px;
}
.padding-sm-h {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.padding-sm-v {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.padding-sm-top {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.padding-sm-right {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.padding-sm-bottom {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.padding-sm-left {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.padding-md {
  padding: 10px;
}
.padding-md-h {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.padding-md-v {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.padding-md-top {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.padding-md-right {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.padding-md-bottom {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.padding-md-left {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.padding-lg {
  padding: 20px;
}
.padding-lg-h {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.padding-lg-v {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.padding-lg-top {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.padding-lg-right {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.padding-lg-bottom {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.padding-lg-left {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.padding-none {
  padding: 0;
}
```